# Python audioop.rms() values from power to amplitude?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, physics, wav

My goal is to compare amplitude measurements from a sound level meter (in *dB SPL*) with simultaneously-recorded audio clips.

[image: audio recording system diagram]

I've been using `audioop.rms()` to summarize the wav audio clips.

I wrote a quick function to convert from the raw sample power to decibels full scale:

```
def valueDBFS(value, sampleWidth):

    # use the sample width to look up the appropriate maximum sample size
    lookupBitDepth = {3: 8388607 , 2: 32768}

    return 10*np.log10(abs(value)/lookupBitDepth[sampleWidth])
```

[Unfortunately the resulting ratio of powers is proportional to the square of Sound Pressure Level, a ratio of amplitudes](http://www.indiana.edu/~emusic/acoustics/amplitude.htm).

I could fix the problem by taking the square-root of *dBFS*, but the units would become totally arcane. I'd much rather use a well-known relative scale to produce a linear comparison between the instruments.

---

QUESTIONS:

1. Is there an alternative to using `audioop.rms()` such that
   I can summarize the pressure amplitude of a wav file?
2. Or, alternatively, is there a way to modify my function such that it
   transforms rms power values into pressure and returns them on a well-known decibel scale?